# Accepting an image as an input by reading a JSON schema?

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

In a JSON Schema we can specify what type of entity we are expecting such as a string like

"Name": {
    "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
    ]
}

Can we do something same for expecting images as input?

Answer (score 4):

JSON Hyper-Schema defines a `media` keyword that can allow you to specify an image as an input.  Most JSON Schema validators don't support Hyper-Schema, but if you have one that does, this could be useful.

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "media": {
        "binaryEncoding": "base64",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
}
```

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html#anchor10